# Help needed in Javascript + Image + HREF

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the above code, I am appending a javascript onclick method to the image tag. When I click the image once and I press back, it should go back to the page it came from. Instead its staying on the same page. Is there any way I can avoid that? (probably set something else instead of `href="#"`). The reason I set `href="#"` is to make my cursor turn into hand, other than that it has no use.

This is occuring in Firefox. In IE it works fine.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/" part from the image URL, to make the example more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" onClick="alert('hi'); return false;"/></a>
```

you need add `return false;` to your onclick events if you don't want to load the link.

Comment: Not exactly related to this issue, but its better to have the click event on `a` than on `img`

Comment: @Teja, yes I would say on `a`

Answer (score 4):

> The reason I set href="#" is to make
>   my cursor turn into hand, other than
>   that it has no use.

You can remove the `<a href="#">` and add the `cursor: pointer` style to the image:

`<img src="logo.gif" style="cursor: pointer;" />`

... to turn the cursor into a hand.

On the other hand, it is probably better to follow the guidelines for progressive enhancement, as [David suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433185/help-needed-in-javascript-image-href/2433201#2433201).

Comment: more info here on @Daniel's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433185/help-needed-in-javascript-image-href/2433193#2433193

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#">
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" 
    onClick="alert('hi'); return false;"/>
</a>
```

`return false` prevents the default action from occurring (in this case navigating to "#"), and then navigating back will return you to the previous page, instead of to the current page without "#".

Answer (score 1):

Follow the pragmatic guidelines for [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/). In particular: Build on things that work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:
    <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" onClick="alert('hi')" style="cursor:pointer"/>