# How do I create a link using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, hyperlink

I have a string for a title and a string for a link.  I'm not sure how to put the two together to create a link on a page using JavaScript.  Any help is appreciated.

The reason I'm trying to figure this out is because I have an RSS feed and have a list of titles ands URLs.  I would like to link the titles to the URL to make the page useful.

I am using jQuery but am completely new to it and wasn't aware it could help in this situation.

Comment: Are you loading the RSS feed with jQuery or something (Mootools, Dojo, Atlas, etc...)? If you're trying to dynamically create anchor tags based on a third-party RSS list acquired on page load, I would suggest using the jQuery library or other to add the element. The details in this case are important to know what needs to be done. However, DOM methods are a useful illustration.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2433199/5996253) I think it can be beneficial

Answer (score 290, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
      a.appendChild(linkText);
      a.title = "my title text";
      a.href = "http://example.com";
      document.body.appendChild(a);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a very generic example of using DOM methods to add an anchor tag to a page. For instance, the appendChild method could be a list element, TD, or other element within the page. See: http://www.quirksmode.org/

Comment: @Nadu - Please stop editing my answer. If you want a specific thing to be said, add one of your own; if it's not "different" enough to warrant it, it's not different enough to warrant an edit.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/mV7nOBIHa6hMNaVIPG75?p=preview I have been created a plunker example.

Answer (score 71):

### With JavaScript

1. ```
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.setAttribute('href',desiredLink);
   a.innerHTML = desiredText;
   // apend the anchor to the body
   // of course you can append it almost to any other dom element
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
   ```
2. ```
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += '<a href="'+desiredLink+'">'+desiredText+'</a>';
   ```

   or, as suggested by [@travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414/travis) :

   ```
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += desiredText.link(desiredLink);
   ```
3. ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //note that this case can be used only inside the "body" element
   document.write('<a href="'+desiredLink+'">'+desiredText+'</a>');
   </script>
   ```

### With JQuery

1. ```
   $('<a href="'+desiredLink+'">'+desiredText+'</a>').appendTo($('body'));
   ```
2. ```
   $('body').append($('<a href="'+desiredLink+'">'+desiredText+'</a>'));
   ```
3. ```
   var a = $('<a />');
   a.attr('href',desiredLink);
   a.text(desiredText);
   $('body').append(a);
   ```

In all the above examples you can append the anchor to any element, not just to the 'body', and `desiredLink` is a variable that holds the address that your anchor element points to, and `desiredText` is a variable that holds the text that will be displayed in the anchor element.

Comment: I think that the only one that you left out is: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += desiredText.link(desiredLink);`

Comment: In order to avoid XSS, you should avoid string concatenation (`+`) and `.innerHTML` when building HTML. With jQuery, `.attr("href", desiredLink)` and `.text(desiredText)` are what you want here.

Answer (score 20):

**Create links using JavaScript:**

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
document.write("<a href=\"www.example.com\">");
document.write("Your Title");
document.write("</a>");
//-->
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('Your Title'.link('http://www.example.com'));
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.innerHTML = 'Google';
newlink.setAttribute('title', 'Google');
newlink.setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');
document.body.appendChild(newlink);
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

There are a couple of ways:

If you want to use raw Javascript (without a helper like JQuery), then you could do something like:

```
var link = "http://google.com";
var element = document.createElement("a");
element.setAttribute("href", link);
element.innerHTML = "your text";

// and append it to where you'd like it to go:
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

The other method is to write the link directly into the document:

```
document.write("<a href='" + link + "'>" + text + "</a>");
```

Comment: I definitely like the first option better. +1 for that, but mixing JS and HTML mixes content and behavior, which should be separate.  Overdone, that can lead to a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I tend to prefer the first option as well, but perhaps using JQuery to achieve the same effect (for readability and ease of maintenance).

Comment: You should probably avoid using document.write http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520440/javascript-document-write-overwriting-page

Answer (score 5):

Dynamically create a hyperlink with raw JavaScript:

```
   var anchorElem = document.createElement('a');
   anchorElem.setAttribute("href", yourLink);
   anchorElem.innerHTML = yourLinkText;

   document.body.appendChild(anchorElem); // append your new link to the body
```

Comment: Use ` anchorElem.text = yourLinkText; ` instead of innerHTML that'll be more clear. And yes consider what'll happen if yourLinkText is maybe " < - that's cool !"

Answer (score 5):

```html
    <script>
      _$ = document.querySelector  .bind(document) ;

        var AppendLinkHere = _$("body") // <- put in here some CSS selector that'll be more to your needs
        var a   =  document.createElement( 'a' )
        a.text  = "Download example" 
        a.href  = "//bit\.do/DeezerDL"

        AppendLinkHere.appendChild( a )
        

     // a.title = 'Well well ... 
        a.setAttribute( 'title', 
                         'Well well that\'s a link'
                      );
    </script>
```

1. The 'Anchor Object' has its own*(inherited)* properties for setting the link, its text. So just use them. **.setAttribute** is more general but you normally don't need it. `a.title ="Blah"` will do the same and is more clear!
   Well a situation that'll demand **.setAttribute** is this: `var myAttrib = "title"; a.setAttribute( myAttrib , "Blah")`
2. Leave the protocol open.
   Instead of **http:**//example.com/path consider to just use //example.com/path.
   Check if example.com can be accessed by **http:** as well as **https:** but 95 % of sites will work on both.
3. ***OffTopic:*** That's not really relevant about creating links in JS
   but maybe good to know:
   Well sometimes like in the chromes dev-console you can use `$("body")` instead of `document.querySelector("body")` A `_$ = document.querySelector`will 'honor' your efforts with an *Illegal invocation* error the first time you use it. That's because the assignment just 'grabs' **.querySelector** (a ref to the **class**  method). With `.bind(...` you'll also involve the context (here it's `document`) and you get an **object** method that'll work as you might expect it.

Answer (score 0):

A *dirty* but **quick** way to create elements:

```js
const linkHTML = `<a
  class="my-link"
  style="position: absolute; right: 0"
  href="https://old.reddit.com"
  title="Go to old reddit"
>
  Old Reddit
</a>`;

  // create element
  const linkEl = strToElement(linkHTML);

  // add element to document.body
  document.body.appendChild(linkEl);

// utility function that converts a string to HTML element
function strToElement(s) {
  let e = document.createElement('div');
  const r = document.createRange();
  r.selectNodeContents(e);
  const f = r.createContextualFragment(s);
  e.appendChild(f);

  e = e.firstElementChild;
  return e;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

You paste this inside :

`<A HREF = "index.html">Click here</A>`

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking for creating a link with JavaScript (not HTML) !