# Adding links with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` element that when clicked updates content on a page. How do I go about adding a link with this JS code?  I made a JSFiddle of basically my question.  Basically the `""` are ending too soon so there must be a character like `%20` to do my dirty work.  Is it possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/BpCSm/

```
$("#content").html("<a herf="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>");
```

Comment: The following SO ticket has the answer for you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript

Comment: Please look at the console when running your code, you will see you have syntax errors..

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes inside the double quotes:

```
$("#content").html("<a href='http://www.google.com'>google.com</a>"); } ); });
```

Also, it's not `herf` but `href`

This is the adapted Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/BpCSm/4/

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to up vote / accept an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to handle this

Using combination of singlequote and doublequote like this `"'"` or `'"'`

```
$("#content").html("<a href='http://www.google.com'>google.com</a>");
```

or , using the escape character like this `"\""` or `'\''`

```
$("#content").html("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google.com</a>");
```