# how to create an html link out of list items through javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking to see if anyone here knows how to **dynamically** generate html out of list items.

Step 1. Here is my HTML list

```
<ol id="list">
  <li class="class1">a<span class="class2">1</span></li>
  <li class="class1">b<span class="class2">2</span></li>
  <li class="class1">c<span class="class2">3</span></li>
  <li class="class1">d<span class="class2">4</span></li>
  <li class="class1">d<span class="class2">so on</span></li>
</ol>
```

Step 2. I have no idea where to start, but my goal is to **dynamically** make something like this

http://www.test.com/?color=1,2,3,4,etc
*Note that the order is the same as in the HTML list

Any suggestion would be wonderful. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't really know what to try. Most questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript) talk about how to make a link through javascript. I don't know how to go about using existing data to make a link. Even if I use document.getelementbyid, I wouldn't know what the id would be since they are all the same.

Comment: It's not actually very clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to take the numbers seen in step 1 and put them into a url (step 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="generate">
</ul>

<button id="btn">Make LI tags</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function create(description)
{
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.id = 'idName';
li.className = 'className';
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(description));  // description will be the text inside li
document.getElementById('generate').appendChild(li);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function()
{
create('text');
}, false);
```