# How to rewrite an element to a link in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, web

I am new to Firefox, what is the easiest way to dynamically change something like

```
<td class="something"><div style="width: 200px;">
randomtext
```

to

```
<td class="something"><div style="width: 200px;">
<a href="www.somewhere.com/randomtext">randomtext
</a></div></td>
```

on an external webpage (a page not under my control)

While searching I found Greasemonkey, but it doesn't look very user-friendly. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some context? Are you writing a Firefox plugin/extension? Is this for a website you are building?

Comment: You want to change it for you? For everybody? Is that your site?. May be done through GreaseMonkey but you'll need to give your script to other people wanting to see the link.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I am trying to load an external page on Firefox and make that bit of text a link to another page. I'll update the question

Comment: Still, do you use an iframe to load the page, or is your server reading it and giving it back to the browser?

Comment: I just use Firefox to load an external page. In this page, somewhere, there will be a <div> with a random piece of text in it. After the page loads, I want Firefox to make that random piece of text a link to www.example.com/radompieceoftext. I've looked at Greasemonkey, but it seems overly complicated and not very user-friendly. I can't be the first person to want to do this, so hopefully someone has an easier way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Greasemonkey - Replace text with link to that text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905306/greasemonkey-replace-text-with-link-to-that-text)

Answer (score 0):

Using **GreaseMonkey** you'll be able to modify the page you load from Firefox. But only for you, if you want other to have the same behaviour you'll have to give them you script.

You can also prepare a Javascript script used as a bookmark : **[bookmarklet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)**

Here again, if you want others to have it you'll have to give it to them.

Comment: A bookmarklet would probably be easiest to make, thank you! Do you by happen chance know a snippet of javascript that can do what I want?

Comment: @JaapBaanders http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript