# How to insert a JavaScript variable in href?

Tags: java, javascript, variables, href

I'm trying to put a JavaScript variable in the `href`.

```
<a href="http://google.com/{$order.paymentBefore}/{$order.guid}">click here</a>
```

When I am using `href`, because I want the link to appear as "Click here", it stays in the link as it is --> `{$order.paymentBefore}/{$order.guid}`, unchanged.

Comment: What  template engine were you expecting was going to parse that variable? WHat langauge are the variables created in

Comment: wirte a function that generates the href. You can not mix html and js like you did.

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript

Answer (score 7):

Use **`click event`** for `<a>` as below

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="redirectTo();">click here</a>
```

**JavaScript function**

```
function redirectTo(){
     var parameter1 = $order.paymentBefore; // some thing like this you can set value for 1st Param.
     var parameter2 = $order.guid; // some thing like this you can set value for 2nd Param.
    window.location.href="http://google.com/"+parameter1+"/"+parameter2;

}
```

Comment: @NikaKvezereli - if above answer is useful for you then `accept` the answer and `upvote` it will be helps other to find correct solutions.

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can mention href value upto what static value you have and the variable can be given in onclick call. See below example:

```
    var orderLink= "xyz";
     <a style="font-size:large;align-content:center" 
href="http://<static value>" onclick="location.href = this.href + orderLink; return false;"> Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, include a function that changes the href of  to what you want. You cannot use it the way you have.

Let your html  tag look something like this.

```
<a id="hyperlink" href="#">Click Here</a>
```

Now create a javascript function which updates the url whenever you call it.

```
function myFunction() { //Call this function whenever you want to update the href
    var link = document.getElementById("hyperlink");
    link.href = "http://google.com/" + $order.paymentBefore + "/" + $order.guid;
}
```