# How to display HTML contained in a JS var?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm looking about how to display HTML from a JS var.

I stocked it in a JSON, but when I want to display it (I return it from a meteor helper), it appears in plain text. I need it to treat the elements as HTML elements.

For example, if my var contains : `"<a href='http://stackorverflow'>Go to the awesome site</a>"`

I want it to display clearly as follow :

[Go to the awesome site](http://Go%20to%20the%20awesome%20site)

I've looked for that on SO and google, but all I found was how to stock HTML to a var, not how to display it.

Could someone show me the way ?

Thanks you,

David

Comment: Checkout this answer: [Javascript variable access in HTML][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4772817/4896724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, for safety purposes, Meteor will render any html code coming from helpers as "escaped" (visible) HTML. To render raw html in your template, Meteor Spacebars give us the [triple-brace](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#triple-braced-tags) notation:

```
{{{html_var}}} <!-- this will be considered as html -->
```

Use this with caution though! Beware of [XSS injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)