# JavaScript: copy text to clipboard and append source hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I do simple website dev with HTML, CSS, and WordPress. I can implement JavaScript, and trial-and-error with it just a little, but I'm not good with it, at all.

I have a client who wants the functionality of Tynt, but they want it activated when a button is clicked (on button click, text is copied to clipboard, and hyperlink appended). Basically, they want to make sharing their content as easy as possible, but they want to encourage attribution as well.

I've used the "Complex Example" found in the 2nd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript), and simply added "+ document.location.href" to the end of the text copied. Everything works, but the link pastes as plain text, not as an active hyperlink.

I tried combining it with the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript), but couldn't figure out how to append the hyperlink to the copied text.

Here's what I have (note: this is just partial, take a look at the referenced questions if you'd like to see the complete code - I'm just trying to figure out how to append an active hyperlink to copied text).

```
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-btn'),

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('Text. Powered by: ' + document.location.href);
});
```

Clicking the HTML button with the class js-copy-btn and pasting produces this:

"Text. Powered by: http://websiteaddress.com"

However, the link pastes as plain text rather than as a hyperlink. How do I force the link to paste as a hyperlink rather than plain text?

Comment: have you tried copyTextToClipboard('Text. Powered by: <a href="' + document.location.href + '">' + document.location.href + '</a>');

Comment: Yes I have. It pastes as plain text. The anchor element tags shows up as plain text.

Comment: Where/what application are you pasting this into? Not all applications “accept” anything else but plain text content from clipboard.

Comment: I'm pasting multiple locations to see how it pastes: a gmail message, a MS Word document, and an HTML text area. In all three cases if I use HTML anchor tags I get the anchor tags themselves pasted as plain text, and if don't use anchor tags I get the website address in plain text.

If I just use the website address (no anchor tags) then it does convert into an active hyperlink as soon as I hit enter or spacebar, but the client wants it's to paste as an active hyperlink - which is what Tynt does.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem recently and solved it. I hope you have also solved it but still want to post the answer as I couldn't find any straight away solution to this.

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(range);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("text copied");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('copyDiv')">Click to copy</button><br/>
    <div id="copyDiv">
      <label>Text. Powered by: </label>
      <a href="http://websiteaddress.com">http://websiteaddress.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Put all the elements inside a div which you want to copy to clipboard(**as is**) and call the function on button click or any other event along with the div id.

Comment: Super helpful snippet, thanks a ton - was able to tweak it to do what I need, and helped me understand how it works

Comment: That was a perfect help