# javascript DOM-add href and <a> link

Tags: javascript, url, dom, hyperlink, href

i did a table that include id name and link. I want to make a link take to the page that it is assigned to when you click it. I tried different ways but it doesn't work.

so i want my links to take to the page when you click it

here is what i got so far

```
var companies = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Google',
        link: 'http://google.com/'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Microsoft',
        link: 'http://microsoft.com/'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Apple',
        link: 'http://apple.com'
    }
];



var tbl = document.createElement("table");
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

var tr_head = document.createElement("tr");

var th_id = document.createElement("th");
var th_name = document.createElement("th");
var th_link = document.createElement("th");

th_id.textContent = "Id";
th_name.textContent = "Name";
th_link.textContent = "link";

tr_head.appendChild(th_id);
tr_head.appendChild(th_name);
tr_head.appendChild(th_link);

thead.appendChild(tr_head);

for(var i = 0;  i < companies.length; i++) {
    var tr_body = document.createElement("tr");

    var td_id = document.createElement("td");
    var td_name = document.createElement("td");
    var td_link = document.createElement("td");

    var id = companies[i].id;
    var name = companies[i].name;
    var link = companies[i].link;

        //link-------------------

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute("href", link);
        td_link.appendChild(a);


    td_id.textContent = id;
    td_name.textContent = name;
    td_link.textContent = link;

    tr_body.appendChild(td_id);
    tr_body.appendChild(td_name);
    tr_body.appendChild(td_link);


    tbody.appendChild(tr_body);

    //css----------------------
    td_id.style.padding = "10px";
    td_id.style.border = "1px solid black";

    td_name.style.padding = "10px";
    td_name.style.border = "1px solid black";

    td_link.style.padding = "10px";
    td_link.style.border = "1px solid black";

}

//css -----------
tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";

th_id.style.padding = "10px";
th_id.style.border = "1px solid black";

th_name.style.padding = "10px";
th_name.style.border = "1px solid black";

th_link.style.padding = "10px";
th_link.style.border = "1px solid black";

tbl.appendChild(thead);
tbl.appendChild(tbody);

console.log(tbl);

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Parag Datar, but the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772817/3204135 will cover the missing link text. 
In your code, it may look something like this:

```
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", link);
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(link);
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    td_link.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `td_link.textContent = link;` line and you are good !