# Trigger click event hyperlink's generated after calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control

I have a web page available in two modes:- default and hosted in a WebBrowser control. My links in the page are setup after some calculations so cannot be static. If user clicks the generated link, that opens in a new page. When in webbrowser control, I want all links to be intercepted and the call handled in the webbrowser container.
I tried to generate a link using  [How do I create a link using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript) but it seems that although the click event fires, the page being targeted doesn't opens.

Any way which I can trigger the opening of new page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look below code, It would be helpful for you to open new tab in `WebBrowser control`

`window.open(url, '_blank').focus();`

Hope it helps you