# how can i add a javascript variable to link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I was trying to add javascript variable in link_to. but name appear as "+item_id+"  not as a variable.  my code is below.

```
  var item_id = item[0]

  $('#item').append('<%= link_to '+ item_id +' , prd_item_path('+ item_id+') %>')
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  Describe your problem more precisely please

Comment: ERB tags (`<%= link_to .. %>`) don't exist in jquery land. So no, it's impossible to "add javascript variable to link_to". But it seems that you just want an `<a>` tag. That you _can_ do. (ProTip: realizing the difference between client-side and server-side and the wall between them is crucial if you want to have anything even remotely complex done).

Comment: but how can i use <a> tags to redirect a new path could you explain more

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing server side with client side code. Keeping in mind that the link_to helper is rendered as a "normal" anchor tag, and that you can't mix the ERB code passing JS values, then you can use that anchor, and concatenate the JS values.

Try with:

```
$('#item').append('<a href="item/' + item_id + '">' + item_id + '</a>')
```

Being `item/` the URI of `prd_item_path`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create ERB elements at the client side. ERB is rendered at the server side.

Create the link at the client using JS, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript)