# Console Javascript Tag

Tags: console

How do I make a link-text? I want to show how I tried do it. [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATkZR.png)[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElJxb.png)[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZzJ3.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "link-text". Can you clarify? Do you mean a link that's styled as regular text?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, links are defined with the  tag:

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Links</h2>
<p><a href="https://www.google.com">Visit google</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

with javascript see here [How do I create a link using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript)