# str.link() , Cannot read property 'link' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

```js
      var str = (data.User.g.number)
                  infoWindow.setContent(str.link("sms://" +  (data.User.g.number))) ;
                  infoWindow.open(map, this);
```

I created this code that creates a link in javascript with str.link. However, this method is not supported on all browsers which is why I got this error. I was wondering if anyone knows of an alternative method to what I want to accomplish or with the code I provided or knows why this code isn't working. I basically need to create a link only using javascript and be able to insert a variable in the link.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g412q.png)

Comment: Does [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) not work? `window.open` works with a string-interpolated link, but I've never used the sms protocol.

Comment: Can I create a label for the link if I use window.open?

Comment: I want to create a link that can be used as a label and the user can click

Comment: So inject a link into the dom. You can do a string interpolated link there too. Also str.link has support being actively removed according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link), so it shouldn't even be kept as a backup. All it does is create an anchor (`<a>` tag) so just do that using the DOM and it's functionally equivalent.

Comment: What is `infoWindow`? Normal elements don't have a `setContent` method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript