# How to build URL from HTML without FORM

Tags: html, forms, rest, url

I know how to use a form tag to make a URL from HTML:

```
<form action="/api" method="get">
    Color: <input type="text" name="color" value="blue"><br>
    Shape: <input type="text" name="shape" value="cirle"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Gives me /api?color=blue&shape=cirle

Is there any way to do this without using a form? For example, for a row of table with the colums as data? E.g.

```
<tr action="/api" method="get">
    <td type="text" name="color" value="blue">Blue</td>                                              
    <td type="text" name="shape" value="cirle">Cirle</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript You could get the input values to create the link.

Comment: @rgiller yes - JS is the answer. I was so focused on an alternative with HTML that I forgot about a JS option. Thanks!