# convert text to link inside for specific element inside loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I created a code to convert json data to html table using javascript and ajax:

Data:

```
[
["text1", "https://www.amazon.com", "text2", "https://www.ebay.com"],
["text3", "https://www.google.com", "text4", "https://www.yahoo.com"],
...
]
```

This is the code, it work well, but on the table result, the **td** containing links is text (column2 and column4,
I want to put the text inside href so the cell become link (instead of text):

```js
const TabBody = document.querySelector("#tab > tbody") 
function loadData() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("get", "rows.json");
    request.onload = () => {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            populateTable(json);
            }  catch (e) {
                console.warn("error");
            }   
        };

    request.send();
}
function populateTable(json){

    while(TabBody.firstChild){TabBody.removeChild(TabBody.firstChild);}

    json.forEach((row) => { 
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");

        row.forEach((cell) => {
            const td = document.createElement("td");
            td.textContent = cell;
            tr.appendChild(td);})

        TabBody.appendChild(tr);
    })            
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { loadData();})
```

```html
<body>
    
    <table id="tab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column_1</th>
                <th>column_2_link</th>
                <th>column_3</th>
                <th>column_4_link</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a link using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just adding a `td` with you can generate a link inside by checking the string with a [Regular Expresion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) if that's your intention:

```
const td = document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML = /https:\/\//g.test(cell)
  ? `<a href="${cell}">${cell}</a>`
  : cell;
tr.appendChild(td);
```

You could create an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) if [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not safe for you, but that should get you going.

Comment: good answer, amazing, but I have an issue: many links in column 2 and column 4 didn't contain http, (many start with www.aliexpress.com/ and many starts with ae01.alicdn.com) but all contains this substring: ".com/"

Comment: @maxscender you can change the regular expression to whatever suits you best, maybe checking for dots or `.com` or `www`

Comment: It worked, thanks, by the way, I can add another test if the link contains specific subtring become src inside img element instead of becoming simple link?

Comment: Totally, you can play with it as you'd like! If it worked make sure to mark the answer accordingly

Comment: you can edit your answer according to 2 possibilities ? if contains ".com/" then it's link, if contains "alicdn.com" then image

Comment: @maxscender I think you already have the information needed to do it youself! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing you one sample. Here, on clicking the update link button, it will update all td that have a link to a clickable item , ie it will get updated with an anchor tag

```
function populateTable(json){

var regex = new RegExp("(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})"); // expression here

    while(TabBody.firstChild){TabBody.removeChild(TabBody.firstChild);}

    json.forEach((row) => { 
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");

        row.forEach((cell) => {
            const td = document.createElement("td");
            
            if(regex.test($(this).text())){
                    td.innerHTML = `<a href="${cell}">Link</a>`;
                }
                else{
                td.textContent = cell;
                }
                            
            tr.appendChild(td);})

        TabBody.appendChild(tr);
    })            
}
```

Complete sample code for testing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  // $('#tbl>tbody').find('td').css("background-color", "yellow");
   
   var regex = new RegExp("(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})"); // expression here


   $('table').find("td").each(function(data) {
   if(regex.test($(this).text())){
   $(this).html(`<a href="${$(this).text()}">Contact</a>`)
   }
       
    
});
    
    
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>  <tr>
    <td>123123</td>
    <td>https://www.amazon.com</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>123123</td>
    <td>https://www.amazon.com</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>


<button>Update Link</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good answer thanks, I can implement the function inside the loop of my code ?

Comment: you can edit your answer to add the solution to the loop inside my code ?