# How do I add a hyperlink in my text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm really new to JS and I tried googling but it did not help. All I'm trying to do is add the medium Post link into my text as a hyperlink. I'm pretty sure I'm half way there but I can't figure it out:

```js
_$ = document.querySelector.bind(document) ;
var AppendLinkHere = _$("body") // <- put in here some CSS selector that'll be more to your needs
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.text = "Medium Post";
a.href = "https://medium.com/@FundsFi/fundsfi-presale-terms-are-here-whitelisting-requirements-fc798d85b284";

// AppendLinkHere.appendChild(a)
// a.title = 'Well well ... 
// a.setAttribute('title', 'Well well that\'s a link');
```

```html
<s.TextDescription style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "var(--primary-text)", }}> 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  Medium Post. 
</s.TextDescription>
```

All I want to do is make it so that when people click on the word Medium Post it takes them to a new tab with the medium link. Also, I got the code from this post while searching for an answer: [How do I create a link using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript) And then I realized that I need to added a CSS selector which I can't figure out how to do. So far I've found this post about: [How do you add CSS with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript)

Comment: what is `<s.TextDescription` ? What programming language does this come from?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Asking not to downvote is pointless. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Incidentally, [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) is different from [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Comment: Adding  css selector is not the same as adding CSS see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Why did you choose code with a syntax error from an answer with 5 votes when there is an accepted answer which will do what you need with 257 votes?

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting it to be javascript this might help.

```js
// create anchor link element
let link = document.createElement("a")

// Create txt
let txt = document.createTextNode("Medium Post")

//append txt to anchor element
link.appendChild(txt)

// set the title
link.title ="Medium Post";

// set the href property
link.href = "https://www.medium.com";

// get text to add link to
let el = document.getElementById("p")

// append the link to the el id = "p"
el.appendChild(link)
```

```html
<div class="textDescription">
  <p id="p">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want an HTML page to include a text that a user can click to go to a new lab that has your link, well there is a lot of ways you can do this including writing in in HTML code instead of javascript so it'll be
`<a href="link here" target="_blank">medium</a>` and that will show a hyperlink text on the page that when clicked would take you to a new page or if you want to use javascript you can use the `document.querySelector("id here").innerHTML = '<a href="link here" target="_blank">medium</a>';` and that would allow you to show the link inside the page and link on an event if set up with `document.addEventListener` but keep in mind that it will remove all the code, text and tags inside the selected tag and put the link.
Sorry if I got something wrong, I'm still kinda new :D

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, the `<div>` element with an `id` value of `link` is added to the `<a>` element when the page's `load` event occurs.

```js
let linkElement = document.getElementById('link');
const targetAddress = "https://medium.com/@FundsFi/fundsfi-presale-terms-are-here-whitelisting-requirements-fc798d85b284";

/* The load event is triggered when the page loads. */
window.onload = function() {
  /* The new <a> element is created. */
  var newLinkElement = document.createElement('a');
  
  /* A new text node is created. */
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Medium Post");
  
  /* The text node is added to the <a> element. */
  newLinkElement.appendChild(newContent);
  
  /* The class attribute of the <a> element is assigned the value "aElementStyle". */
  newLinkElement.setAttribute('class', 'aElementStyle');
  
  /* The targetAddress variable content is assigned to the href attribute of the <a> element. */
  newLinkElement.setAttribute('href', targetAddress);
  
  /* The <a> element is linked as a child to the <div> element whose id value is "link". */
  linkElement.appendChild(newLinkElement);
}
```

```css
.aElementStyle {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="link"></div>
</body>
```